# Css radial gradient, new syntax

Tags: html, css, gradient, radial-gradients

I had a perfectly valid ([judging by the look](http://jsfiddle.net/oj7fr558/1/)) radial gradient :

```css
.square {
    background-color: #f0d9b5;
    color: #b58863;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grad:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #00f;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square grad"></div>
```

I had no problem with it, till I found that [all these prefixes are not needed for a gradient.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients). Removing them actually removes the gradients in corresponding browsers. It looked like the problem is that there is another (newer) syntax for [css gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).

The problem is that if change my background to:

`background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50% , #00f 0%, #fff 100%);` the result looks different:

```css
.square {
    background-color: #f0d9b5;
    color: #b58863;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grad-first:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #00f;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
}

.grad-second:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #00f;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50% , #00f 0%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square grad-first"></div>
<div class="square grad-second"></div>
```

Which looks like it is removing my first background on `.square`. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was specifying `#fff` as the color stop. That creates a solid white color stop, rather than a transparent one. There are no other cross-browser issues with the old and new radial gradient syntaxes that I am aware of.

Note that changing it to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` can have a different result than changing it to `rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)` in some browsers like Firefox. This may be due to how Firefox interpolates transparent color stops depending on their RGB values. Use `rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)` (transparent blue) in order to get consistent results across all browsers:

```css
background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50% , #00f 0%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0) 100%);
```

(You can also change `#00f` to `rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)` for consistency if you like, but it's not absolutely necessary.)

```css
.square {
    background-color: #f0d9b5;
    color: #b58863;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grad-first:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #00f;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center center,circle cover,rgba(0,0,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
}

.grad-second:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #00f;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50% , #00f 0%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square grad-first"></div>
<div class="square grad-second"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse result looks different because you use this 
background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50% , #00f 0%, #fff 100%);

use use two colors #00F and #FFF.
due to #FFF color the result looks different so use #f0d9b5 instead of #FFF then result looks same as u need